# Word to mean "alien poison"

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m making a comic in which I’m recreating [these posters](http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/40869f0a844611e1af7612313813f8e8_6.jpg), but with aliens, instead of rats.

Now, my first thought was *xenocide*, but that pretty much just means “genocide of an alien species” ever since Orson Scott Card's book where I think he created the word.

But *rodenticide* has *-i-* as a connector, not just *-cide* so could *xenoicide* or *alienicide* show what I’m trying to say?

My question is, which one of these words (or maybe ones I haven’t thought of) most appropriately conveys "*alien poison*" in one word?

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: *Aliens* in *xeno-* refers to strangers, not what you seem to imply ("alien species").

Comment: @Kris In scifi works, *xeno-* is often used to refer to alien species.

Comment: A *-cide* is a "killer", not a poison. A *toxin* is a poison. A poster like that needs to be self-explanatory first, while also being catchy/ witty if possible.

Comment: I wonder if you could come up with a name or place of origin for the aliens you're implying need to be poisoned in the comic. If they're Jovians, you could call it Jovicide.

Comment: *-icide* is not a suffix; the suffix is [*-cide*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cide) (from Latin -cida) and the stem is *rodenti-* from [*Rodentia*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rodentia)

Comment: @MarkBeadles, You're right about the suffix, but I think the stem is rodent- with the connective vowel -i-.

Comment: @LittleBigBot If that were so, then how would _matricide_, _fratricide_, _suicide_, _uxoricide_, etc. work?

Comment: @coleopterist Well, I'm mainly going by these: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rodenticide and http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pesticides

Comment: That's why I was careful to use the term "stem" and not "root" :)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Exotoxoids" roughly fits the meaning you want to convey, and the two exxes add comic-book-writing-style memorability.

Comment: I like it, I was just thinking of "xenotoxin" but yours seems more of a marketable term, if such a thing did exist. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I think Xenotoxin has a better ring to it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't see why you can't use *xenocide*. Genocide is "the deliberate and systematic destruction, *in whole or in part*, of an ethnic, racial, religious, or national group". Therefore, *xenocide* should fit just fine.

If you're looking for a neologism, you could use the concoction of *exobiocide* ([exobiology](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exobiology) + [biocide](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/biocide)). For those familiar with its history, *barbaricide* ([barbarian](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=barbarian) + *cide*, not to be confused with [Barbicide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbicide)) might also work.

Comment: But what I am trying to convey is a physical thing, whereas genocide and xenocide aren't.

Comment: Technically, _pesticide_, _fungicide_, etc. are constructed similarly, but have evolved/been adapted to represent a class of chemicals. You can do the same with your neologisms.